# Iterating deeply nested pandas json object?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pretty big json object which is of the format

```
[
  {
   "A":"value",
   "TIME":1551052800000,
   "C":35,
   "D":36,
   "E":34,
   "F":35,
   "G":33
  },
 {
  "B":"value",
  "TIME":1551052800000,
  "C":36,
  "D":56,
  "E":44,
  "F":75,
  "G":38
  }, ...
...
]
```

Converted to json with the help of pandas

`df.to_json(orient='records')`

I want to loop through the json body and update a specific key inside this json object and send it back to the client through my api

I want to do something like

```
for i = 0
   object[i]["TIME"] = updateCaclulations
   return i
```

I am new to python and have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397285/iterate-over-all-items-in-json-object). It helps iterate through the object but updation is not there and the time taken due to recursion is a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pd.read_sql_query returns pd.DataFrame and not json.

As per your question:

Say you have a sample function calculate:

```
def update_calculation(time):
    return time
```

You could update time so:

```
df["TIME"] = df["TIME"].apply(update_calculation)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason blocking you from performing the calculation before converting the dataframe to json?

Comment: Well, I had some problems with the format for the dataframes. Solved them now. Thanks!