# Convert a nested key with values list to string value in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have some JSON files that are very nested.
This are converted from xml to JSON using xmltodict.

Some of the vaules where there are a lot of text have be put in a list, but for the most of the time they are just strings.

All of the texts values are in a ['P'] value.

I well find every ['P'] of value list and convert them to sting.

```
if isinstance(t['DOFFIN_ESENDERS']['FORM_SECTION']['CONTRACT']['FD_CONTRACT']['LEFTI_CONTRACT']['F02_CONDITIONS_FOR_PARTICIPATION']['ECONOMIC_OPERATORS_PERSONAL_SITUATION']['P'], list):
            t['DOFFIN_ESENDERS']['FORM_SECTION']['CONTRACT']['FD_CONTRACT']['LEFTI_CONTRACT']['F02_CONDITIONS_FOR_PARTICIPATION']['ECONOMIC_OPERATORS_PERSONAL_SITUATION']['P'] = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in t['DOFFIN_ESENDERS']['FORM_SECTION']['CONTRACT']['FD_CONTRACT']['LEFTI_CONTRACT']['F02_CONDITIONS_FOR_PARTICIPATION']['ECONOMIC_OPERATORS_PERSONAL_SITUATION']['P']])
        else:
            pass
```

This does work, but I have to write 2000 line of code to change every value.
So I have tryed with this object_hook function on JSON files, but it dont do what I well.

```
def mydata_hook(obj):
    #obj_d = dict(obj)
    if obj['P'] in obj and isinstance(obj, list):
        obj['P'] =  str('P').strip('[]')
    else:
        return(obj)
        
    

path = 'C:/doffin/test/'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.json'):
        continue
     
    
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(fullname, 'rb') as f:
        jsonstr = f.read()

    json_sting = json.loads(jsonstr, object_hook=mydata_hook)
    json_str2 = json.dumps(json_sting)
    
    with open(fullname[:-4] + ".json", 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_str2)
```

EDIT:
One of the files look like this.

```
{
    "DOFFIN_ESENDERS": {
        "VERSION": "V3.0.2",
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "DOFFIN_ESENDERS.xd",
        "xmlns": {
            "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        },
        "FORM_SECTION": {
            "F52_2014": {
                "LG": "NB",
                "CATEGORY": "ORIGINAL",
                "FORM": "F52",
                "CONTRACTING_BODY": {
                    "ADDRESS_CONTRACTING_BODY": {
                        "OFFICIALNAME": "Halden Kommune",
                        "NATIONALID": "959159092",
                        "ADDRESS": "Storgata 8",
                        "TOWN": "HALDEN",
                        "POSTAL_CODE": "1751",
                        "COUNTRY": {
                            "VALUE": "NO"
                        },
                        "CONTACT_POINT": "Svein Andersen",
                        "PHONE": "+47 69174500",
                        "E_MAIL": "svein.andersen@halden.kommune.no",
                        "LOCATION": {
                            "code": "000000"
                        },
                        "URL_GENERAL": "https://permalink.mercell.com/128099026.aspx",
                        "URL_BUYER": "http://www.halden.kommune.no/"
                    },
                    "DOCUMENT_FULL": null,
                    "URL_DOCUMENT": "https://permalink.mercell.com/128099026.aspx",
                    "ADDRESS_FURTHER_INFO_IDEM": null,
                    "URL_PARTICIPATION": "https://permalink.mercell.com/128099026.aspx"
                },
                "OBJECT_CONTRACT": {
                    "TITLE": {
                        "P": "Forvaltning og utbygging av fiberinfrastruktur i Halden Kommune"
                    },
                    "REFERENCE_NUMBER": "2020/2088",
                    "CPV_MAIN": {
                        "CPV_CODE": {
                            "CODE": "64214400"
                        }
                    },
                    "TYPE_CONTRACT": {
                        "CTYPE": "SERVICES"
                    },
                    "SHORT_DESCR": {
                        "P": ["Halden kommune inviterer til \u00e5pen anbudskonkurranse for forvaltning og utbygging av fiberinfrastruktur i Halden Kommune.", "De siste \u00e5rene har Halden kommune investert i fiberinfrastruktur i kommunen parallelt med oppgradering av vann- og avl\u00f8psutbedringer. \u00a0I \u00e5rene som kommer har kommunen en m\u00e5lsetting om \u00f8kt utbygging av fiberinfrastruktur til offentlige bygg, n\u00e6ringsbygg og privatpersoner i Halden.", "Kommunen \u00f8nsker derfor \u00e5 legge best mulig til rette for utbygging ved \u00e5 innlede samarbeid med en virksomhet som kan ivareta kommunens, n\u00e6ringslivets og privatpersoners interesser best mulig.", "Kommunen \u00f8nsker samtidig \u00e5 redusere kommunens kostnader knyttet til fibertjenester inn til offentlige bygg."]
                    },
                    "NO_LOT_DIVISION": null,
                    "OBJECT_DESCR": {
                        "ITEM": "1",
                        "CPV_ADDITIONAL": {
                            "CPV_CODE": {
                                "CODE": "45232300"
                            }
                        },
                        "LOCATION": {
                            "code": "030101"
                        },
                        "SHORT_DESCR": {
                            "P": ["Gjennom anskaffelsen \u00f8nsker Halden kommune \u00e5 kunne levere tjenester til sine interne og eksterne kunder p\u00e5 en bedre m\u00e5te. Form\u00e5let med denne anskaffelsen er \u00e5 inng\u00e5 avtale med en leverand\u00f8r som kan ivareta f\u00f8lgende arbeider for kommunen:", "1. \u00a0 Videreleie/ selge kapasitet p\u00e5 kommunens eksisterende fibernett.", "2. \u00a0 Bygge ut og leie/ selge fiberkapasitet i kommunens tilgjengelige trekker\u00f8r.", "3. \u00a0 Informere akt\u00f8rer om gr\u00f8fter som graves i forbindelse med vedlikehold av kommunens vann- og avl\u00f8ps-", "nett.", "4. \u00a0 Administrere og drifte fibernettverket og dokumentere fremtidig infrastruktur.", "5. \u00a0 Bist\u00e5 med utarbeidelse av s\u00f8knader om midler til utbygging av fiber", "Denne anskaffelsen f\u00f8lger prosedyre for \u00e5pen anbudskonkurranse med bruk av hasteprosedyre. Hensyntatt den spesielle situasjonen rundt korona-utbrudd og viktigheten av informasjon ut til alle innbyggere settes det i gang med denne anskaffelsen. Anskaffelsen foretas innenfor et omr\u00e5de som defineres som samfunnskritisk infrastruktur hvor kommunen har et s\u00e6rlig ansvar for \u00e5 bidra til at det foretas videre utvikling og utbygging.", "Anskaffelsen innehar to konkrete utbyggingsprosjekter og i tillegg en forvaltning og utbyggingsdel for kommunen."]
                        },
                        "AC_PROCUREMENT_DOC": null,
                        "DURATION": {
                            "TYPE": "MONTH",
                            "text": "24"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "LEFTI": {
                    "QUALIFICATION_CRITERIA_DOC": null
                },
                "PROCEDURE": {
                    "PT_OPEN": null,
                    "OTHER_INFORMATION": {
                        "P": "Denne anskaffelsen f\u00f8lger prosedyre for \u00e5pen tilbudskonkurranse med bruk av hasteprosedyre. Hensyntatt den spesielle situasjonen rundt korona-utbrudd og viktigheten av informasjon ut til alle innbyggere settes det i gang med denne anskaffelsen. Anskaffelsen foretas innenfor et omr\u00e5de som defineres som samfunnskritisk infrastruktur hvor kommunen har et s\u00e6rlig ansvar for \u00e5 bidra til at det foretas videre utvikling og utbygging."
                    },
                    "DATE_RECEIPT_TENDERS": "2020-05-08",
                    "TIME_RECEIPT_TENDERS": "15:00",
                    "LANGUAGES": {
                        "LANGUAGE": {
                            "VALUE": "NO"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "COMPLEMENTARY_INFO": {
                    "DATE_DISPATCH_NOTICE": "2020-04-22"
                }
            }
        },
        "DOFFIN_APPENDIX": null
    }
}
```

Some of the "P" keys are list like on line 50

```
"SHORT_DESCR": {
                        "P": ["Halden kommune
```

and on line 64

```
"SHORT_DESCR": {
                            "P": ["Gjennom anskaffelsen
```

while on line 80 its a string

```
"OTHER_INFORMATION": {
                        "P": "Denne anskaffelsen
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to join lists of strings in your json, if they are contained in a (possibly nested) dictionary with a key value of "P". This seems like the perfect job for recursion:

```py
import glob
import json

def process_json(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if "P" in obj and isinstance(obj["P"], list):
            obj["P"] = " ".join([str(e) for e in obj["P"]])
        for element in obj.values():
            mydata_hook(element)

for path in glob.glob("C:/doffin/test/*.json"):
    with open(path) as fi:
        data = process_json(json.load(fi))
    
    with open(SOME_OUTPUT_PATH, "w") as fo:
        json.dump(data, fo)
```

Comment: Hi i did try you code but it dont work. for element in obj.values():
            mydata_hook(element) whats mydata_hook now? golb.glob dont take a "C:/PATH" so path = "C:/doffin281220/test/" and for path in glob.glob(path + '\\*.json'): I did update my post with one of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I did find another post for dealing with this and change the code and added some part of your code.
The other post are [Iterate over all items in json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397285/iterate-over-all-items-in-json-object)

The upgaded code that works are

```
def recursive_iter(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for item in obj.values():
            if "P" in obj and isinstance(obj["P"], list):
                obj["P"] = " ".join([str(e) for e in obj["P"]])
            else:
                yield from recursive_iter(item)
    elif any(isinstance(obj, t) for t in (list, tuple)):
        for item in obj:
            yield from recursive_iter(item)
    else:
        yield obj

path = "C:/doffin281220/test/"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.json'):
        continue
     
    
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(fullname, 'rb') as f:
        jsonstr = f.read()

    json_sting = json.loads(jsonstr)
    for item in recursive_iter(json_sting):
        json_str2 = json.dumps(json_sting)
    
    with open(fullname[:-4] + ".json", 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_str2)
```

This reads all JSON files in a folder and save the new updated with the same filename +..json

The file that I have in the org. post looks like this now.

```
{
    "DOFFIN_ESENDERS": {
        "VERSION": "V3.0.2",
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "DOFFIN_ESENDERS.xd",
        "xmlns": {
            "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        },
        "FORM_SECTION": {
            "F52_2014": {
                "LG": "NB",
                "CATEGORY": "ORIGINAL",
                "FORM": "F52",
                "CONTRACTING_BODY": {
                    "ADDRESS_CONTRACTING_BODY": {
                        "OFFICIALNAME": "Halden Kommune",
                        "NATIONALID": "959159092",
                        "ADDRESS": "Storgata 8",
                        "TOWN": "HALDEN",
                        "POSTAL_CODE": "1751",
                        "COUNTRY": {
                            "VALUE": "NO"
                        },
                        "CONTACT_POINT": "Svein Andersen",
                        "PHONE": "+47 69174500",
                        "E_MAIL": "svein.andersen@halden.kommune.no",
                        "LOCATION": {
                            "code": "000000"
                        },
                        "URL_GENERAL": "https://permalink.mercell.com/128099026.aspx",
                        "URL_BUYER": "http://www.halden.kommune.no/"
                    },
                    "DOCUMENT_FULL": null,
                    "URL_DOCUMENT": "https://permalink.mercell.com/128099026.aspx",
                    "ADDRESS_FURTHER_INFO_IDEM": null,
                    "URL_PARTICIPATION": "https://permalink.mercell.com/128099026.aspx"
                },
                "OBJECT_CONTRACT": {
                    "TITLE": {
                        "P": "Forvaltning og utbygging av fiberinfrastruktur i Halden Kommune"
                    },
                    "REFERENCE_NUMBER": "2020/2088",
                    "CPV_MAIN": {
                        "CPV_CODE": {
                            "CODE": "64214400"
                        }
                    },
                    "TYPE_CONTRACT": {
                        "CTYPE": "SERVICES"
                    },
                    "SHORT_DESCR": {
                        "P": "Halden kommune inviterer til \u00e5pen anbudskonkurranse for forvaltning og utbygging av fiberinfrastruktur i Halden Kommune. De siste \u00e5rene har Halden kommune investert i fiberinfrastruktur i kommunen parallelt med oppgradering av vann- og avl\u00f8psutbedringer. \u00a0I \u00e5rene som kommer har kommunen en m\u00e5lsetting om \u00f8kt utbygging av fiberinfrastruktur til offentlige bygg, n\u00e6ringsbygg og privatpersoner i Halden. Kommunen \u00f8nsker derfor \u00e5 legge best mulig til rette for utbygging ved \u00e5 innlede samarbeid med en virksomhet som kan ivareta kommunens, n\u00e6ringslivets og privatpersoners interesser best mulig. Kommunen \u00f8nsker samtidig \u00e5 redusere kommunens kostnader knyttet til fibertjenester inn til offentlige bygg."
                    },
                    "NO_LOT_DIVISION": null,
                    "OBJECT_DESCR": {
                        "ITEM": "1",
                        "CPV_ADDITIONAL": {
                            "CPV_CODE": {
                                "CODE": "45232300"
                            }
                        },
                        "LOCATION": {
                            "code": "030101"
                        },
                        "SHORT_DESCR": {
                            "P": "Gjennom anskaffelsen \u00f8nsker Halden kommune \u00e5 kunne levere tjenester til sine interne og eksterne kunder p\u00e5 en bedre m\u00e5te. Form\u00e5let med denne anskaffelsen er \u00e5 inng\u00e5 avtale med en leverand\u00f8r som kan ivareta f\u00f8lgende arbeider for kommunen: 1. \u00a0 Videreleie/ selge kapasitet p\u00e5 kommunens eksisterende fibernett. 2. \u00a0 Bygge ut og leie/ selge fiberkapasitet i kommunens tilgjengelige trekker\u00f8r. 3. \u00a0 Informere akt\u00f8rer om gr\u00f8fter som graves i forbindelse med vedlikehold av kommunens vann- og avl\u00f8ps- nett. 4. \u00a0 Administrere og drifte fibernettverket og dokumentere fremtidig infrastruktur. 5. \u00a0 Bist\u00e5 med utarbeidelse av s\u00f8knader om midler til utbygging av fiber Denne anskaffelsen f\u00f8lger prosedyre for \u00e5pen anbudskonkurranse med bruk av hasteprosedyre. Hensyntatt den spesielle situasjonen rundt korona-utbrudd og viktigheten av informasjon ut til alle innbyggere settes det i gang med denne anskaffelsen. Anskaffelsen foretas innenfor et omr\u00e5de som defineres som samfunnskritisk infrastruktur hvor kommunen har et s\u00e6rlig ansvar for \u00e5 bidra til at det foretas videre utvikling og utbygging. Anskaffelsen innehar to konkrete utbyggingsprosjekter og i tillegg en forvaltning og utbyggingsdel for kommunen."
                        },
                        "AC_PROCUREMENT_DOC": null,
                        "DURATION": {
                            "TYPE": "MONTH",
                            "text": "24"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "LEFTI": {
                    "QUALIFICATION_CRITERIA_DOC": null
                },
                "PROCEDURE": {
                    "PT_OPEN": null,
                    "OTHER_INFORMATION": {
                        "P": "Denne anskaffelsen f\u00f8lger prosedyre for \u00e5pen tilbudskonkurranse med bruk av hasteprosedyre. Hensyntatt den spesielle situasjonen rundt korona-utbrudd og viktigheten av informasjon ut til alle innbyggere settes det i gang med denne anskaffelsen. Anskaffelsen foretas innenfor et omr\u00e5de som defineres som samfunnskritisk infrastruktur hvor kommunen har et s\u00e6rlig ansvar for \u00e5 bidra til at det foretas videre utvikling og utbygging."
                    },
                    "DATE_RECEIPT_TENDERS": "2020-05-08",
                    "TIME_RECEIPT_TENDERS": "15:00",
                    "LANGUAGES": {
                        "LANGUAGE": {
                            "VALUE": "NO"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "COMPLEMENTARY_INFO": {
                    "DATE_DISPATCH_NOTICE": "2020-04-22"
                }
            }
        },
        "DOFFIN_APPENDIX": null
    }
}
```