# An elegant way to strip (trim) all string values in a JSON

Tags: python, json

As an example, I would like to convert this JSON:

```
{
    "abcd": "  Something here",
    "foo": [
        "ab 123 ",
        " pp wer ",
        {
            "xyq": [[["  going deeper "]]]
        }
    ],
    "nested": {
        "name": "   Santa ",
        "age": 1234
    }   
}
```

into this one:

```
{
    "abcd": "Something here",
    "foo": [
        "ab 123",
        "pp wer",
        {
            "xyq": [[["going deeper"]]]
        }
    ],
    "nested": {
        "name": "Santa",
        "age": 1234
    }   
}
```

Obviously, this can be implemented by parsing the JSON into a dict/list tree structure, recursively walking through that tree and modifying the leafs where needed. I wonder, is there an elegant and easy way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over all items in json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397285/iterate-over-all-items-in-json-object)

Comment: @Andreas Not quite. In my case I am asking about trimming (modifying) the JSON data structure in-place, not just reading it.

Comment: Neither your input nor your output represent valid JSON. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Are you looking for "an elegant and easy way" to _"parse the JSON into a dict/list tree structure, recursively walk through that tree and modify the leafs where needed"_ or a way to avoid this?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I don't mind a solution with a recursion. I just posted such a solution as a possible answer. I would be happy to know if there is something simpler.

Comment: 1. convert JSON to python dict, 2. walk the object either recursively or otherwise, 3. trim any strings you encounter, 4. write back out to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution I could come up with. Would be happy if someone can suggest something simpler.

```
def trim_dict_or_list(item):
    if type(item) is list:
        for i, v in enumerate(item):
            if type(v) is str:
                item[i] = v.strip()
            else:
                trim_dict_or_list(v)
    elif type(item) is dict:
        for k, v in item.items():
            if type(v) is str:
                item[k] = v.strip()
            else:
                trim_dict_or_list(v)


with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    jj = json.load(f)
trim_dict_or_list(jj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your json data is stored in a file as text, or is available as string, than you can use regex. It can be done with the `json`-module form the standard library with `dump` and `load`. [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```
import re

jsons_text = """"
{
    "abcd": "  Something here",
    "foo": [
        "ab 123 ",
        " pp wer ",
        "hey": {
            "xyq": [[["  going deeper "]]]
        }
    ],
    "nested": {
        "name": "   Santa ",
        "age": 1234
    }   
}"""
# remove space on the left
json1 = re.sub(r'"\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])', '"\1', json_text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
# remove space on the right
json2 = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+"', '\1"', json1, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(json2)
```

I don't know if it is elegant enough but at least it doesn't explicitly need dynamic structures.

Comment: It could have been elegant if it worked. Try with this: `json_text = '{"abc": " one \"  two  "}'`.

Comment: well if you know your strings won't contain escaped quotes this solution is fine. Exercise is left to the reader if you care about escaped quotes or not

Comment: well the above program does its job given the above string. I cannot figure out a universal solution if I don't have all information available. Make a list of possibles trim-patterns and apply them then...

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be implemented in a much easier way:

```
def strip(data):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return data.strip()
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [strip(element) for element in data]
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {key: strip(value) for key, value in data.items()}
    return data
```