# Iterate through JSON object, retreive most inner first

Tags: python, json, recursion

Having a JSON that looks like this (sample)

```
"version": 16,
    "customer[split]Invoice.Customer": {
        "authorizedAt": null,
        "createdAt": "2022-07-27 19:27:22",
        "zip": "3141",
        ...
    },
    "invoice[split]Invoice": {
        "externalInvoice": 0,
        "invoiceTriggeredByUser": true,
        ...
        "billingAddress": {
            "company": null,
            ...
        },
        "marketPartner[split]Invoice.MarketPartner": {
            ...
        }
    },
    "contracts": [
       {
           "contract[split]Invoice.Contract": {
               "startDate": "2007-05-10",
               "endDate": null
               ...
           }
       }
    ]
```

Now, whereever there is a key that has `[split]` inside, I want to cut everthing that is inside, put it in a new file named like everything after the `[split]` and replace everthing that is inside with a reference to the new file. So

```
"customer[split]Invoice.Customer": {
        "authorizedAt": null,
        "createdAt": "2022-07-27 19:27:22",
        "zip": "3141",
        ...
    },
```

becomes

```
"customer": {
    "$ref": "./models/Invoice.Customer.json"
},
```

Doing this for the first level is easy:

```
    def __split_object(self, keys: list):

        # We build the new Event from Scratch and make everything a $ref
        build_event = {}
        for key in keys:
            # Check if it does not contain a [split]
            if key.find('[split]') == -1:
                """
                Just use it as it is
                """
                build_event[key] = self.__input_event[key]
            else:
                """
                1. Split the content to another file.
                2. Name it like everything after [split]
                3. Replace everything in the new event with a $ref
                """
                # 1. Split
                new_content = self.__input_event[key]

                # 2. Name it and save it accordingly
                key_names = key.split('[split]')
                file_name = key_names[1]
                object_name = key_names[0]

                with open('output/models/{}.json'.format(file_name), 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(new_content, f, indent=4)

                # 3. Replace it inside the new one with a $ref
                build_event[object_name] = {
                    '$ref': './models/{}.json'.format(file_name)
                }

        return build_event
```

And then use it with

```
        with open('data/events/' + input_file, encoding='utf-8') as json_data_file:
            self.__input_event = json.load(json_data_file)

        build_event = self.__split_object(list(self.__input_event.keys()))
```

I also found other SO Questions that deal with the recursion, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397347/1092632 but I cannot wrap my head around how I would go to the deepest level first, without knowing how deep it goes. So for example the `invoice` object will contain a `"$ref": "./models/Invoice.json` and inside that `Invoice.json` the `marketPartner` contains `"$ref": "./models/Invoice.MarketPartner.json"`

`contracts` may also be an issue, because it is an array / list, but I think I can handle that myself if I get the first part right.

Any hint on where to start is highly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to go through the dictionary recursively without an exit condition and store the highest level and furthermost element

Comment: So something like: Check if we are in the lowest level, if yes, do we need to split, if yes, split and then run it again? That would mean an "in place" manioulation of the original json, right? Currently I am "building" a new one.

Comment: I would say its something like... check if the element has nested children, if it does, keep going. If it doesnt compare it's level (recursive function must keep track of level) to the current highest level. If the level is greater, store the element and its level. Once the recursion is over because there are no elements left, return the stored element.